# How are these odds created?

Tags: odds-ratio, odds

I've always been a bit baffled by how Vegas creates sports odds. Not so much the process of how did the oddsmakers decide that Option A has odds of X/Y (that obviously is fairly subjective and not something anyone here can answer) but the statistical methodology. Let me give an example.

Here are some current odds for the 2018 Heisman trophy winner in college football:

```
Player                  Odds
Bryce Love              7/1
Jonathan Taylor         8/1
Khalil Tate             9/1
Tua Tagovailoa          10/1
J.K. Dobbins            12/1
Jake Fromm              12/1
Jarrett Stidham         12/1
Will Grier              12/1
Justin Herbert          15/1
Kelly Bryant            15/1
McKenzie Milton         18/1
Trace McSorley          18/1
Cam Akers               22/1
Jake Browning           22/1
Rodney Anderson         25/1
Ryan Finley             25/1
Brandon Wimbush         35/1
D'Andre Swift           35/1
Nick Fitzgerald         35/1
Travis Etienne          35/1
David Sills             45/1
Ed Oliver               55/1
Nick Bosa               75/1
```

So I guess what confuses me is the distribution of odds. Altogether, those add up to 557/1. I don't get that. Shouldn't odds add up to 100?

What does this all mean percentage wise? So it's saying Bryce Love has X% to win. What's the percentage?